# How to use onSetClickListener with Interstitial ads and Intent together?

Tags: java, android, interstitial

I'm using a click listener for both interstitial ads and intent to pass control to another activity:

Can anyone modify below code to use it together?

```
register_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
             mInterstitialAd.show();
         }
     } 
});

register_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent register_intent = new Intent(home.this,register.class);
         startActivity(register_intent);
     }
});
```

Comment: Are you serious?

Answer (score 0):

If this:

```
register_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
        Intent register_intent = new Intent(home.this, register.class);
        startActivity(register_intent);
    }
});
```

is not what you want/doesn't work, then your flow is incorrect.